# Automation_agent and qtp_air resource bundles not found when adding automation libs to AIR project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, automation, qtp

I'm trying to add the automation libraries to my project in Flash Builder so we can automate our testing.

I've added this to the additional compiler settings:

```
-include-libraries+="${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation.swc","${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_agent.swc","${flexlib}/libs/automatio n/automation_dmv.swc","${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_spark.swc ","${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_air.swc","${flexlib}/libs/aut omation/automation_airspark.swc","${flexlib}/libs/automation/qtp_air.swc"
```

and `-locale nl_BE fr_BE`

After compiling this I get 2 errors:

```
Unable to resolve resource bundle "automation_agent"
Unable to resolve resource bundle "qtp_air"
```

However, in my **nl_BE** and **fr_BE** folders under `flex_sdk\frameworks\locale\` the **automation_agent_rb.swc** and **qtp_air_rb.swc** are present.

If I switch to **en_US**, it works fine.

Can somebody explain to me why Flash Builder can't find these resource bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly adding automation_agent_rb.swc and qtp_air_rb.swc to your library-path as well.